# Unity layer masks

Tags: unity, unity-ui, layers

I read from the book that 0 - 7 layers are reserved layers in Unity but when I open layers on Unity its showing me that I can use layer-03, 6 and 7 and so on. So can I say that only 5 layers are reserved not 7 ?

[image]

Comment: What do your tests reveal? Trust tests over books. Books can tell you what worked when they were written (if the author wasn't mistaken). Tests will tell you what actually works today.

Comment: test reveal 5, does it mean it contain 5 reserved layers? but I also read that they reserved 2 for future use and future versions